# How to create new matrix with the condition of one variable in R?

Tags: r, for-loop, matrix

I have a variable  `x`  of length`20` as

```
x
 [1] 3 3 1 2 3 1 2 1 3 1 3 1 3 2 1 1 3 1 3 2.
```

Now I would like to create a matrix of order `20 by 2` 
where the first column  `W_i1` is filled with `1` if `x==1` and `-1` if `x not equal to 1`. Similarly, the second column is filled with `1` if `x=2` and `-1` if `x not equal to 2`. If `x=3`, both the column are filled by `-1`. Here is the expected outcome

```
W_ij
      [,1] [,2]
 [1,]   -1   -1
 [2,]   -1   -1
 [3,]    1   -1
 [4,]   -1    1
 [5,]   -1   -1
 [6,]    1   -1
 [7,]   -1    1
 [8,]    1   -1
 [9,]   -1   -1
[10,]    1   -1
[11,]   -1   -1
[12,]    1   -1
[13,]   -1   -1
[14,]   -1    1
[15,]    1   -1
[16,]    1   -1
[17,]   -1   -1
[18,]    1   -1
[19,]   -1   -1
[20,]   -1    1
```

I can do it for each column separately and recorded as a matrix

```
W_i1=ifelse(x==1,1,-1)
W_i2=ifelse(x==2,1,-1)
W_ij=matrix(c(W_i1,W_i2),
             nrow = 20,
             ncol =2,
             byrow = F)
```

Can I do it using any loop?

Any help is appreciated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way you could transform this is

```
cbind(x == 1, x == 2) * 2 - 1

     [,1] [,2]
 [1,]   -1   -1
 [2,]   -1   -1
 [3,]    1   -1
 [4,]   -1    1
 [5,]   -1   -1
 [6,]    1   -1
 [7,]   -1    1
 [8,]    1   -1
 [9,]   -1   -1
[10,]    1   -1
[11,]   -1   -1
[12,]    1   -1
[13,]   -1   -1
[14,]   -1    1
[15,]    1   -1
[16,]    1   -1
[17,]   -1   -1
[18,]    1   -1
[19,]   -1   -1
[20,]   -1    1
```

Answer (score 3):

We could do in a single step with

```
replace(cbind( c(-1, 1)[(x==1) + 1], c(-1, 1)[(x==2) + 1] ), x == 3, -1)
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]   -1   -1
# [2,]   -1   -1
# [3,]    1   -1
# [4,]   -1    1
# [5,]   -1   -1
# [6,]    1   -1
# [7,]   -1    1
# [8,]    1   -1
# [9,]   -1   -1
#[10,]    1   -1
#[11,]   -1   -1
#[12,]    1   -1
#[13,]   -1   -1
#[14,]   -1    1
#[15,]    1   -1
#[16,]    1   -1
#[17,]   -1   -1
#[18,]    1   -1
#[19,]   -1   -1
#[20,]   -1    1
```

---

As some of the steps are similar, can create a function

```
f1 <- function(vec, v) c(-1, 1)[(vec == v) + 1]
replace(cbind(f1(x, 1), f1(x, 2)), x == 3, -1)
```

#### data

```
x <- c(3, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 3, 2, 1, 1, 3, 1, 3, 2)
```